# Test cafe: Page timeout after submit

Tags: automation, automated-tests, timeout, e2e-testing, testcafe

Having some issues with Test Cafe after clicking a "Filter" button to assemble a report. Here is my code:

```
         ...
         await report.accessReportBanks(testData.page + '/reports/report_banks');

         const filterButton = Selector('input').withAttribute('type', 'submit').withAttribute('value', 'Filter');

         await t
             .click(filterButton);
             .wait(120000)
             .expect(Selector('tbody').child('tr').count).gt(0, "Expects results for Report Banks");
     });
```

The `click` action works fine, but timeout seems to be expiring before expected, and the browser ends up in a blank screen with no error message, except the URL:

http://192.168.50.249:55753/eUn3KSCLI/about:error

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Already have this values set on .testcaferc.json

```
{
     "assertionTimeout": 60000,  // Defines the maximum time TestCafe will wait the elements to be "ready" before performing an assertion
     "pageLoadTimeout": 60000,   // Defines the maximum time TestCafe will wait the page be "ready" before performing an assertion
     "quarantineMode": true,     // The quarantine mode is designed to isolate non-deterministic tests from the other tests
     "selectorTimeout": 60000    // Defines the maximum time TestCafe will wait for a selector be visible
}
```

and also tried to run my test with `--page-load-timeout 120000`, still with no success.

Comment: The test code looks ok. 
Probably the cause of the issue is specific to your site. 
Please provide a working example to demonstrate and reproduce the issue. If you can provide such an example, then please create a separate issue in the TestCafe github repository using the following template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Comment: Site works fine manually. It just takes about 45 to 50 seconds to load after the click on the "filter" button. I'll see if there is a way to make this URL available, as it is for internal use only.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe can abort browser requests if they take more than 20 seconds to complete. We already have a suggestion to allow configuring this timeout: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2940. You can subscribe to it to be notified about the progress in implementing this suggestion.

Alternatively, you can modify the timeout value in the [TestCafe source code](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/blob/master/src/request-pipeline/destination-request/index.ts#L45) and build your own TestCafe version.